# How is it possible that Nib is loading?

Tags: ios, swift

I created new file and check `Cocoa Touch Class` -> Then I set subclass as `UIViewController` -> I mark "Also create XIB file".

It created simple `UIViewController` as expected, but here is my question becuase when I called:

```
present(MyViewController(), animated: true)
```

This shows `MyViewController()` as I wanted but how is it possible that I'm using simple `init()` and Nib is loaded?
 I thought that I need to use different initalizer, how Swift is doing this?

Comment: Have you worked with `Objc` language earlier?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but Objc code will be appreciated too.

Comment: But you posted question nothing in common with this.

Comment: @SohilR.Memon That "duplicate" has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @SohilR.Memon Please remove duplication, cause it's not related question to your link.

Comment: @Tajnero Already done, cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not "Swift" doing this. It's the implementation of the `UIViewController` class. The same happens with Objective-C.

Start by reading the documentation for the `UIViewController init(nibName:bundle:)` method and the `nibName` property.

From the `nibName` documentation:

> If you use a nib file to store your view controller's view, it is recommended that you specify that nib file explicitly when initializing your view controller. However, if you do not specify a nib name, and do not override the loadView() method in your custom subclass, the view controller searches for a nib file using other means. Specifically, it looks for a nib file with an appropriate name (without the .nib extension) and loads that nib file whenever its view is requested. Specifically, it looks (in order) for a nib file with one of the following names:
>
> 1. If the view controller class name ends with the word ‘Controller’, as in MyViewController, it looks for a nib file whose name matches the class name without the word ‘Controller’, as in MyView.nib.
> 2. It looks for a nib file whose name matches the name of the view controller class. For example, if the class name is MyViewController, it looks for a MyViewController.nib file.

Basically, in your case you use the default initializer meaning you specified `nil` for the nib name. So at runtime, the nib you created with the same name as the view controller class is automatically found and used.

Comment: I think it's a duplicate question. A lot of questions are already being answer.

Comment: @SohilR.Memon The question you linked has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: But is it possible that it's calling ini(nibName:bundle:) after init() ?

Comment: @rmaddy It is because the instantiation of `UIViewController` is completely wrong and the link which I have posted provides the perfect way to do so.

Comment: @Tajnero Yes. The `init()` method probably just calls `init(nibName:bundle:)` with `nil` for both parameters.

Comment: @rmaddy You have just given the same answer as the link, is anything different there or Am I missing something?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon The question and title is correct as-is. You are confused.

Comment: @rmaddy And then probably in init(nibName:bundle:) when nibName is nil it searches for appropiate Nib files?

Comment: @Tajnero Yes, just as the documentation I quoted in my answer states.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you, that's what I wanted!

Comment: @SohilR.Memon No, the question you linked is completely different from this question. And the answers in the question you linked are completely different from my answer.

Comment: @rmaddy Got it :)